# meaning of h2o metrics when xval is selected?

Tags: r, cross-validation

When a metric is computed for a trained model with `nfolds` greater than 1 in h2o, what is the value when `xval=TRUE' ?

```
h2o.mse(model, xval=TRUE)
```

Here is my read and please correct me if I'm off. If `nfolds` is 3, it is doing 3-fold cross validation to select the best model. So, the `mse(train=T)` gives the MSE of the best fold of the three models evaluated on the training set. Likewise, `valid=TRUE` gives the error on the validation set by the same model.

But what is the MSE when xval is selected?

According to the `h2o.mse` help page, `xval` is the cross-validation error. So I expect it is the average of the 3 cross-validation runs.

However, when i look at the actual values, `xval` is always lower than `valid`, which contradicted my interpretation above. The best model must have a lower MSE than the average.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `nfolds>1`, H2O will perform k-fold cross-validation for the specific purpose of model evaluation, not model selection.  It will train k models for cross-validation and then a final model on the full training set.  The value of `h2o.mse(model, xval=TRUE)` is the average MSE over the k models trained in the cross-validation process.

The value of `h2o.mse(model, train=TRUE)` will provide the (full) training set MSE and if you passed a separate `validation_frame`, then `h2o.mse(model, valid=TRUE)` will provide the validation MSE.

If you want actually perform model selection (by choosing the best model based on cross-validation error), then take a look at `h2o.grid()`.

Comment: Yet another clarification Q. When `valid` or `train=TRUE`, which model of the `nfolds` models is used? or again it is the average of all the CV models.

Comment: None of the CV models are used in either case.  

The model trained on the full training set is used, and predictions are made either on the `validation_frame` (for `valid=T`) or `training_frame` (for `train=T`).  The numbers returned by `h2o.mse()` for example, when `valid=T` or `train=T`, are completely independent from the CV models.  The only value that uses the CV models is `h2o.mse(model, xval=T)`.

Comment: This is very useful information. Someone needs to put that into the help page.

Answer (score 1):

you can find more details from this in depth question about how H2O's cross validation works https://community.h2o.ai/questions/550/i-am-not-new-to-cross-validation-but-i-am-new-ish.html

and the following H2O docs sections:
Cross Validation Section
http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3706/docs-website/h2o-docs/cross-validation.html

you can also look at the nfolds parameter explanation in the docs appendix